# How to cut specific characters in Bash variable (Without any extra commands)

Tags: bash

My variable is

```
var1="prod/deployment-prod-specific.yml"
```

I want to alter the var1 to remove the `'prod/'` characters while execution.

expected output:

```
echo ${var1}
```

should produce

```
deployment-prod-specific.yml
```

Comment: `echo $(basename "$var1")` would do it in that specific case.

Comment: `echo "${var1#*/}"`

Answer (score 1):

After some research done, it is possible to cut specific characters from a string variable in bash.

var1="prod/deployment-prod-specific.yml"

echo ${var1##prod/}

will produce

deployment-prod-specific.yml

Comment: more like `${var1#*/}` for removing everything from the start up to the first `/`, or `${var1##*/}` for removing  everything from the start up to the last `/`

Comment: @Fravadona Yes, that is working. Thanks